# How does law of karma work?

Tags: karma

If I do seriously  bad karma against other guy, I will obtain result of it. But my question is what will happen to other guy why should he suffer from me. Had he done previously bad karma so is he suffering from my hand? If not How his suffering is balanced out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the karma from the previous life affects the current life?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2249/does-the-karma-from-the-previous-life-affects-the-current-life)

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/38521/4435