# Instances of curses given to commit crimes?

Tags: sin, rebirth, curse

Refer to the comment trail to this [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/38034/29783) for background. My main question was if it is really in the hands of a thief to not thieve. Later the curse to Jaya-Vijaya is discussed. I received useful insights from user [Carmen sandiego](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/18974/carmen-sandiego) - that curse did not specifically say that the two will commit crimes.

Question: Are there any references of curses that said the receiver would commit crimes in current/later births?

On why it might even make sense to give such curses: IMO, forcing a *moral* person to commit immoral acts would be a suffering to them. So if an otherwise moral person does a bad thing (as *might* be the case with Jaya-Vijaya), making them do evils/crimes would be like its consequences.

Comment: Karma is karma. If a 'moral' person commits an immoral act they are no longer moral; they will suffer the karma for the immoral act. They do not avoid the consequences. Maya is like a spider's web; if you pull on one part, the vibrations will be felt in another part of the web. All are subject to the effect of karma. THe Lord is the dispenser of karma, what the consequences are is only known by the Lord.