# According to Hindu scriptures, what do they say about leaving your parents?

Tags: dharma-shastras, parents, adharma

I am somewhere in what you may call “dharma sankat” here.
I know such questions have been asked before but they do not ask it correctly or are answered partially.

Everyone has some negative traits but what shall a son do if he has devoted years to the family and what they have done is disrespected, discouraged and insulted him so much that he had to be put on medications.

I understand that parents are to be given utmost respect and love. But not all apples weigh the same right? What if one has tried many times to move on with them but they never seem to change? (Like Prahlad)

> In one of the verses, Prahalad Maharaj compares this material household life, where the householder is entangled badly, as dark well. Srila Prabhupada suggests the only solution that a householder has in order to free himself from such a deep entanglement

> Thus the household becomes gṛham andha-kūpam, a dark well into which the man has fallen. For such a man to get out is extremely difficult unless he is helped by a strong person, the spiritual master, who helps the fallen person with the strong rope of spiritual instructions. A fallen person should take advantage of this rope, and then the spiritual master, or the Supreme Personality of Godhead, Kṛṣṇa, will take him out of the dark well.

- Srimad Bhagavatam 7.6.11 - 13 Purport

**I am asking this question because I wish to be a knowledgable and apt Hindu, I know the value of parents in our culture.**

Comment: dharma and karma flow top-down. just as a child that is born disabled is to be pitied, but at same time, we know that it did some sin in the past to deserve that punishment.. similarly, a child with crappy parents is to be pitied, but did some sin in past to deserve it. since shastras do not tell us what sins we did in the past, our only guiding light is what they DO tell us i.e. how to live this life to avoid sin. and that is to obey parents/elder brother/husband. shastras have not given us authority to punish our parents

Comment: Many dreadful parents in Hindu mytho, Prahlad dad trying end his life (then Narsimh) Sati’s dad so horrid re her marriage, Veerbhadra decapitate, PrajapatiDaksh w/ goat head, though apparently he apologize Bholenath later. Surya Dev mistreated ShaniDev, made his childhood horrible. And lots others. Anyway, bad parents are so difficult, is possible you can tactfully diplomatically limit interaction using work excuse. Also might help read western psych articles on respectfully setting boundaries, modify for Indian culture. Hopefully someone posts a proper scripture answer below. Hang in there !

Comment: Thank you devibhakt for the recommendation; it is good to know that someone cares and dear @mar. I am not trying to punish anyone, I am just looking a way out for my peace. Even if my soul had tormented someone in the past, does it mean my present self is not allowed for a change? I mean then what is the use of a new body and a new life? Right?

Comment: @MihirUj - are you sure it's a NEW body and NEW life ? we are all here to exhaust our previously done karma. if we continue to do new karma, then we need to take another body/life to exhaust karma accumulated in this birth.

Comment: @mar your idea of apathy means everyone who is raped was because of their karma, everyone who is hurt is because of their karma. You are just apathetic to everything, so let it be. Why do not you exhaust your karma and let others live.

Comment: @MihirUj - you're confusing apathy with justificaiton. everyone who got raped/hurt is because of their karma. and the rapist getting hanged is ALSO part of his karma. there is an infinite chain of action-consequences which cannot be stopped. the best you can do is not get involved in that chain. we can only retroactively justify something due to karma, since Bhagavan is the sole knower/enforcer of it. all we can do is follow dharma shastras. I've written about it at length [before](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/37351/4435)